# How to launch the project from Git?

Tags: java, android, git

i need implement in my project `NumberPicker` and i found [github example](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker) , but i can't migrate it...

as ussual i do migrate two ways

1. Just make `git clone` and open in studio
2. If this way doesn't work i try make imort `file - new - import project` , push next - next and it is opening

But with this project it isn't opening

Who know what the problem? How i can open it?

After i try import as a result i have such screen, without active button `run`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

This project is not an Android Studio project but still an Eclipse project.

Please follow

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-from-eclipse-projects
or
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

to migrate it to an Android Studio project.

Comment: i think not exactly, there are two directories, the first it is library "library", and the second one it is really samples "samples" which should have a `run` button. And as far as i understand issue in gradle files...

Comment: Which Gradle files? That is not a Gradle Project. Maybe that is your problem

Comment: Yes it is not a gradle project, it is a old eclipse project which building without gradle, but i actually need launch this one with Android Studio. How i can make it? It is my question... Studio need gradle to build the project, how can i create a gradle to launch it?

Comment: I googled for you and updated the answer. Next time, please google yourself before asking. ;-)

Comment: )) Thanks, but i have already found this article, and after i try made all as was write and without succes(( i don't know why... Try yourself download this project and lauch it if you will be have succes say me please how? Because i can't understend what i miss((

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Android Studio. I use the full IntelliJ IDEA on which Android Studio is based and there it might behave different behaviour.